# Jumping with quadratic equation -JAVA

Tags: java, math, slick2d, quadratic

### Motion.java

```
package util;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
public class Motion {

    static double origin,speed;
    static double playerX=100,playerY=520, calcY;
    static boolean jump=false;
    static int x=0;
    public static void setSpeed(double speed){
        Motion.speed=speed;
    }
    public static void startMotionDetect(Input input, int delta){
        input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE);
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE))// <<Needs to be worked with depending on where the platform is.
               jump=true;
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)&&playerX+delta*speed<=400)
            playerX+=delta*speed;
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)&&playerX-delta*speed>=0)
            playerX-=delta*speed;
        if (jump)
            jump(delta);
    }
    private static void jump(int delta) {
        playerY=QuadCalc.getY(.00038261911, -.6764705882, 520, x);
        if(x<=1768)
            x+=24;
        else if(x>=1768){
            jump=false;
            x=0;
            playerY=520;
        }
    }
    public static double getPlayerX(){
        return playerX;
    }
    public static double getPlayerY(){
        return playerY;
    }
}
```

### QuadCalc.java

```
package util;
    import java.math.*;
    public class QuadCalc {
    static double a, b, c, x, y;
    public static double getY(double a, double b, double c, double x){
        y=a*Math.pow(x, 2)+b*x+c;
        return y;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make my character jump based on this quadratic equation that I created
(.00038261911x^2-.6764705882x+520). The problem is I can't figure out how to utilize delta in the process of moving the character like I do for moving right and left. I tried to create a separate variable to hold the calculated value for the quad formula than have the playerY-=delta*speed; until it got to the calculated value. This didn't work because the delta would inflate the value too much. Does anyone have any ideas to incorporate the delta with the jumping method I have?

PS: If more information needs given please let me know D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic formula implies calculating position from time, given some acceleration and starting velocity. The delta doesn't even need to be calculated in this case, you simply need to insert the time into the formula and you'll have the current position.

The delta does matter if, say, you are accelerating at a variable rate, or some other such task.

However, if you really want to know, to find the delta you need to take the derivative of the formula, or better yet, a discrete derivative. The derivative of a quadratic, given a*x^2+b*x+c is 2a*x+b. That should be your delta.

Comment: Thank you I was able to fix the problem by multiplying the delta to the x (time). I forgot that x was representing the time in the formula. It works great now!